# HTML radio checked, not working along side AngularJS directive ngModel

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm trying to set a default selection for a radio button, but it's not working when used along side AngularJS directive [ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel)

```
<input type="radio" value="5000" checked ng-model="status">5000
```

Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6q5Lvz7a/)

Comment: Can you explain why is any different the answer you marked as valid and mine that you downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ng-checked in this case. [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6q5Lvz7a/1/)

HTML Code:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="test">
        <input type="radio" value="5000" ng-checked="status">5000
        <br/> <span>{{status}}</span>

    </div>
</div>
```

JS Code:

```
angular.module("myApp", [])

    .controller("test", function ($scope) {
    $scope.status = true;
});
```

UPDATE as per the OP comment:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6q5Lvz7a/3/)

JS Code:

```
angular.module("myApp", [])

    .controller("test", function ($scope) {
    $scope.status = true;
    if (!$scope.status) $scope.radioValue = 0;
    else $scope.radioValue = 5000;
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="test">
        <input type="radio" value="5000" ng-checked="status" ng-model="radioValue">5000
        <br/> <span>{{radioValue}}</span>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but I also want the value of radio button selected .....for which I would require ngModel .... What do u think ??

Comment: Just define a model as well and initialize that in the controller as well.

Comment: @iJay: Updated the code, you can put the false value and see that the value is getting changed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the status scope property in your controller:

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" value="5000" checked ng-model="status">5000
```

JS:

```
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("test", function ($scope) {
    $scope.status = 5000;
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6q5Lvz7a/2/)

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't set a default value, explain what do you expect to happen then